# I want to pass promise value dynamically to the sdk as a parameter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a web3 project. I have sanity as a backend, where I get contract addresses for different tokens.

```
// Requesting Data from sanity
  async  sanityCoins() {
    try{
      const coins =await fetch("https://i7ml51e6.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/query/production?query=*%5B_type%3D%3D'coins'%5D%7B%0A%20%20name%2C%0A%20%20symbol%2C%0A%20%20usdPrice%2C%0A%20%20ContractAddress%2C%0A%20%20logo%0A%7D")
  
      const data = (await coins.json()).result;
      console.log(data)
    }
    
    catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
   
  }
```

***The async function returns this***

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {ContractAddress: '0xBbCd8c1b5993062F2761CF07e27C2adebc55766F', logo: {…}, name: 'Ethereum', symbol: 'ETH', usdPrice: '2,088'}
1: {ContractAddress: '0xb74FbCF3b2e6b29B0b86f005FCC80eC649de7E30', logo: {…}, name: 'Bitcon', symbol: 'BTC', usdPrice: '$30,947'}
2: {ContractAddress: '0x7a6DC36DD8CC525E15C2B14a415253153909fc24', logo: {…}, name: 'Solana', symbol: 'SOL', usdPrice: '52'}
length: 3
```

I want to pass these contract addresses as a parameter to the SDK . Where the SDK takes **Address: string** as a parameter(Thirdweb SDK -https://portal.thirdweb.com/typescript).

```
 sdk = new ThirdwebSDK(
    new ethers.Wallet(
      environment.metamask_Key,
      ethers.getDefaultProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/94ef7ea56a0e4585834ffbb4dfb3f8b8'))
      )
      
      token = this.sdk.getToken("contract Address");//different contract addres goes here

  async data() {
    const tokens = await this.token.balanceOf("0x47444Bfc280Bd50e3a96ccFd031f7539d6B6E97A");//Wallet address
    console.log(tokens);

    try {
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
    
  }
```

`token = this.sdk.getToken("contract Address");` I want to pass the contract address from sanity to the SDK here. Can this be done. I'm asking here as a last resort. I'm not sure how to assign **async value** to a **variable** and use it later("If that's how its done") . Every where I go I only see ReactJS guides for web3. I really don't know how to do this if it is possible.

The SDK still doesn't have a feature where it returns all the tokens for the connected wallet. I asked about this to the team on Discord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Im not sure how to assign async value to a variable and use it later("If thats how its done")

Just assign data in a global variable and use it later.

```
async  sanityCoins() {
try{
  const coins =await fetch("https://i7ml51e6.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/query/production?query=*%5B_type%3D%3D'coins'%5D%7B%0A%20%20name%2C%0A%20%20symbol%2C%0A%20%20usdPrice%2C%0A%20%20ContractAddress%2C%0A%20%20logo%0A%7D")

  const data = (await coins.json()).result;
  console.log(data)
  //assign data
  this.coins = data;
}

catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}}
```

If you want to call sdk to get tokens right after `sanityCoins`, return `data` in `sanityCoins`

```
async function sanityCoins() {
  //...do the fetch, etc.
  return data;
}

// get tokens by contractAddress
async function getTokens(contractAddress) {
    const sdk = new ThirdwebSDK(...);
    const token = sdk.getToken(contractAddress);
    const tokens = await token.balanceOf(...);
    return tokens;
}

//do where you want to get tokens
const coins = await sanityCoins();
const promises = coins.map(coin => getTokens(coin.ContractAddress));
//get all tokens of coins, tokensArray is like [tokens,tokens,...]
const tokensArray = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: when I set it to a global variable and try to get the variable it gives undefined. but if the variable is an array and I do push, it does show up. but then how do I pass it to the SDK using forEach or map? I'm not able to do that. If there's any guide or reference. would be helpful.

Comment: it's undefined because of the async function. so the variable is empty and has to wait till the async function is completed rite?

Comment: I understand how it's done now. But promises cant be map rite. It's throwing me an error saying property map does not exists on promise<void>

Comment: `const coins = await sanityCoins();` did you use `await` before `sanityCoins()`. `sanityCoins()` is a aysnc function, you need to use `await` to get the result of fetch, otherwise you'll get a promise object in `coins`.

Comment: Yea I used it, works fine. but How do I use the values I just got, I have no clue, Because when I console log it. It shows ZoneAwarePromisee. I want to use those values, Can I store them in an array or a variable and use them? how do I do that? Big thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I'm asking this question because it's a bad practice not to use global variables to assign an async value to a global variable. and in Angular, it is suggested to use services if the state is obtained asynchronously

Comment: It's possible to assign an async value (which means a `Promise` object more precisely) to a global variable and use it later, for example `this.coinsPromise = sanityCoins(); // no await here`. when you need to use the value, you must use it like `this.coinsPromise.then(value => {  //use value here })`  or `const value = await this.coinsPromise;`, but the async process (like a fetch) has been already taken place at the time you assign the variable. async/await  is a ES6 feature which has not been implemented in any browsers, it works as Promise now.I think you should learn more about Promise

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood the point of your question. I guess the idea of assign an async value could be based on the business logic of your project, maybe you can solve the problem by reconsidering the logic

Comment: thank you for all the information. Like you said I'm going to learn more about Promise and try to rethink the business logic.